# Converting a short cage rear derailleur to a long cage derailleur

Tags: derailleur

Is it possible to convert a short cage rear derailleur (for example the Huret Svelto) to a long cage derailleur by just taking the lower cage and replacing it by a longer one?

Comment: Of course, you can do it, if you have the long cage and any associated parts.  But about the only way to get a long cage is to take it off another derailer.  And note that, to be "perfect", springs may need to be swapped as well, and the stops may be cut differently on the upper cage (or other differences) depending on whether it's for long or short cage.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the derailleurs are the same model, and you can get all the parts, (which isn't usually a straightforward process) youcan convert from short cage to long cage.

Comment: That's assuming that the rest of the derailleur is constructed the same way, which is not guaranteed. It's an inane problem anyway -- if you could do it, you're cannibalizing a long cage derailleur that you could have just bolted on anyway.

Comment: You might need to adjust the chain length too, especially if you added a bigger sprocket that the short cage couldn't handle.

Comment: Actually, you can order the long cage parts only. You don't necessarily need to cannibalize a long cage derailleur. And you would need to adjust chain length, of course. And if the derailleur so are the same model, as I specified, it would be constructed the same.