# Convert Shimano Ultegra 6870 rear mech from short cage to medium cage

Tags: derailleur

I would like to ride with a 11-32 cassette but I have a short caged Ultegra 6870 derailleur. Can I just swap the cage? Or are there other differences between the derailleurs?

Cheers

Comment: Take a look here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/converting-a-short-cage-rear-derailleur-to-a-long-cage-derailleur?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes.

A single web search for "Ultegra 6870 derailleur spare parts" will find an exploded view diagram with spare part codes. It is fairly clear that the only differing parts are cage plates. The parts go by codes Y5YC98080 and Y5YC25000.

Comment: Consider adding the exploded image?  Great work!

Comment: I'd like to leave it as an exercise to readers. I promise, it's faster than you think and after you do it once, you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if the cage is integral with the rest of the mechanism, or if it can be simply unbolted from both.

You would save yourself having to break the chain, release and reattach the gear wire, and possibly reindexing the gears.

On the downside, there's a good chance the cages aren't going to just simply swap, so you'd be looking at cutting, filing, drilling, bolting, etc.  Adding weight and introducing more failure points

If the bolt holes line up precisely then a cage swap might be workable, but otherwise just change the whole mech.  Its not a big job, just a comparatively dirty one.

Comment: Is this yes, no or really complicated way of saying "I don't know"?

Comment: If you have both derailleurs it would be simpler and more practical to swap them entirely because you'll have to possibility to swap them the other way round without hassle except for the different chain-length.

Comment: @ojs pretty much yes - even knowing the groupset doesn't help a lot.  Direct inspection of the two parts is needed to see if the cage can bolt-off and whether the mount holes line up.  Its 99% likely they won't.   Photos from OP could help a bit too.

Comment: @Criggie actually googling the group set name yielded this diagram with spare part codes: https://www.paul-lange.de/index.php/de/explosionszeichnungen.html?file=files/paullange/07_Service/04_Downloads/Shimano/explosionszeichnungen/RD/RD-6870-3641A.pdf